# OR in a while statement not working

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{
public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;

    while (a != 0 || b != 0){
        System.out.println("");
        a = in.nextInt();
        b = in.nextInt();

    } 
}
}
```

My question is why does "a" AND "b" need to be 0 for the while to stop?
Anything i can do to fix? I could make a new variable and then:

```
 if (a = 0){
      //blabla...
 }
```

but i would rather not...

Comment: `a != 0 || b != 0` means either `a` or `b` should be non-zero, so both would have to be zero for the expression to be true. Just give it some more thought.

Comment: That's just boolean algebra. `a != 0 || b != 0` -> `!(a == 0 && b == 0) `. If you want to stop when `a == 0 || b == 0`, the negative of that is `!(a == 0 || b == 0)` for the condition, which becomes: `a != 0 && b != 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition you have currently:

```
while (a != 0 || b != 0)
```

Is the equivalent of, as @TimBiegeleisen said:

```
while(a == 0 && b == 0)
```

And, as you realized, you don't want that. Fix your condition to this:

```
while(!(a == 0 || b == 0))
```

Because this would be the condition you want.

Your complete code should be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;

        while (!(a == 0 || b == 0)){
            System.out.println("");
            a = in.nextInt();
            b = in.nextInt();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Java `while` loop stops when its condition becomes `false`. According to the laws of logic, the negation of

```
a != 0 || b != 0
```

is

```
a == 0 && b == 0
```

If you want a different breaking condition, then go ahead and add it.

If you want a good read, check out the [Wikipedia article on logical equivalence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence), where you will find, among other things, something called [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which states that:

```
¬(p∨q)≡¬p∧¬q
```

Answer (score 0):

Java while loop will work like

```
while(o) means false, means it will not enter inside the loop
while(1) means true, means it will enter inside the loop.
```

Depending on this condition you can pass the expression to the while loop.